# Showing month wise value when no data exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL Server and I have written the below SQL query in order show me the customer name, town name, product, sale_quantity, sale year, sale month and distributor name and the quantity I have sold on a specific month, however I want the query to show month wise even if there is no data for a month.

```
SELECT dbo.Customerdetl.cust_name, dbo.Towndetl.town_name, dbo.productdetl.prod_desc, dbo.SalesSummary.sales_qty, dbo.SalesSummary.year_numb, dbo.SalesSummary.month_numb,dbo.DistributorDetl.DISTNAME
FROM     dbo.SalesSummary INNER JOIN
                  dbo.productdetl ON dbo.SalesSummary.ProductCode = dbo.productdetl.ProductCode INNER JOIN
                  dbo.DistributorDetl ON dbo.SalesSummary.DistCode = dbo.DistributorDetl.DistCode INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Customerdetl ON dbo.SalesSummary.cust_code = dbo.Customerdetl.cust_code INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Towndetl ON dbo.SalesSummary.town_code = dbo.Towndetl.town_code  
WHERE  (dbo.SalesSummary.year_numb = 2021) AND (dbo.Customerdetl.cust_name = N'Janani Pharmacy') AND (dbo.productdetl.prod_desc = N'Mycotin')
```

The result I'm getting is:

| Cust_name | Town | Product | Sales_qty | Year | Month | Distributor_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 10 | 2021 | 7 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 10 | 2021 | 4 | NEGA |

what i would like to get is:

| Cust_name | Town | Product | Sales_qty | Year | Month | Distributor_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 1 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 2 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 3 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 10 | 2021 | 4 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 5 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 6 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 10 | 2021 | 7 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 8 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 9 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 10 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 11 | NEGA |
| Janani Pharmacy | HANWELLA | Mycotin | 0 | 2021 | 12 | NEGA |

I tried using left join as well but it did not work.

Comment: Very common problem... google calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the Sales table doesn't hold onto records with no sales. Something like this should in 'theory' build out a table that has everything you need.

1. TABLENEEDS gets all distinct year, distcode, productcode, town_code, and cust_code
2. BUILDOUT runs a cross join that applies all months to all distinct sets in TABLENEEDS (assuming that dbo.SalesSummary.month_numb has all 12 months)
3. ADDSALESBACK does exactly that, a left join across all criteria that turns the null values where sales doesn't exist into zeroes.

The final select just displays ADDSALESBACK - you would just do your other joins off of the ADDSALESBACK table instead of dbo.SalesSummary

```
WITH TABLENEEDS AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  dbo.SalesSummary.year_numb,
  dbo.SalesSummary.DistCode,
  dbo.SalesSummary.ProductCode,
  dbo.SalesSummary.town_code,
  dbo.SalesSummary.cust_code,
FROM dbo.SalesSummary
)

,

BUILDOUT AS(
SELECT *
FROM TABLENEEDS
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.SalesSummary.month_numb FROM dbo.SalesSummary) AS MONTHSFORBUILDOUT
)

,

ADDSALESBACK AS(
SELECT
BUILDOUT.*,
COALESCE(dbo.SalesSummary.sales_qty, 0) AS sales_qty
FROM BUILDOUT
LEFT JOIN dbo.SalesSummary
ON dbo.SalesSummary.year_numb = BUILDOUT.year_numb AND dbo.SalesSummary.DistCode = BUILDOUT.DistCode AND dbo.SalesSummary.ProductCode, = BUILDOUT.ProductCode AND dbo.SalesSummary.town_code = BUILDOUT.town_code AND dbo.SalesSummary.cust_code = BUILDOUT.cust_code AND 
dbo.SalesSummer.month_numb = BUILDOUT.month_numb)

SELECT *
FROM ADDSALESBACK
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, however i have seem to run into a problem, i'm getting incorrect syntax near ')'. expecting as, for_path, id or quoted_id in the BUILDOUT part in your code at the end, last bracket in the BUILDOUT part of the code. if can help clarify whats the cause that would be most appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing that since that CROSS JOIN uses a subquery it required a name - I added AS MONTHSFORBUILDOUT as the name in my post

Comment: Hi, it worked i'm getting duplicates: as shown in the link https://snipboard.io/5rKsN9.jpg  there should only be sales qty to for the 4th and 7th month others should be null or zero for the sales qty

Comment: I was missing a qualifier in the where clause for month_numb - add AND 
dbo.SalesSummer.month_numb = BUILDOUT.month_numb - I edited my code as well